# python paramiko connect with fileinput

Tags: python, paramiko, file-io

I need to run a command on multiple servers and I am using below code:

```
    import paramiko, getpass, fileinput

    username = raw_input("Enter your username [%s]: " % getpass.getuser())
    passwd = getpass.getpass("Enter your password: ")
    serverlist = raw_input("Enter the server list file path with filename: ")

    for line in fileinput.input([serverlist]):
        paramiko.util.log_to_file('paramiko.log')
        s = paramiko.SSHClient()
        #s.load_system_host_keys()
        s.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        s.connect(line, 22, username, passwd)
        stdin, stdout, stderr = s.exec_command('uptime')
        print stdout.read()
        s.close()
```

But, this code is producing below error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "test_paramiko.py", line 15, in 
        s.connect(line, 22, username, passwd)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 277, in connect
        socket.getaddrinfo(hostname, port):
    socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

I am not sure what I am missing here. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably got unknown host name from `serverlist`. Add something like:

```
print('Connecting with "%s"...' % (line))
```

This name can contain CR, LF, space or be empty. Check it. If it has newline then use

```
hostname = line.strip()
print('Connecting with "%s"...' % (hostname))
s.connect(hostname, 22, username.strip(), passwd.strip())
```

The same is for `username`, and `passwd` variables. But be sure you user names and passwords cannot ends with space or other whitespace. Instead of `strip()` you can use `rstrip()`.

Comment: Yes, use `strip()` or `rstrip()` string method.